# Unidentified column were newly created

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Unidentified column  uu

```
SELECT DISTINCT *,
        (CASE  c.userid WHEN '1' THEN c.user2id ELSE c.userid END) as uu 
FROM chats as c INNER JOIN  users as e ON   c.uu = e.id
```

Comment: `sql-server <> mysql` .. Pick one! Also edit your question or go through the help center to see how to write a good question

Comment: who what is ''(chats,'' ?? you have miss char ?

Comment: The FROM clause is taken care of before the SELECT list. I.e. the FROM clause can't reference column alias uu since it doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use sub query as you want to combine two column's data into one (based on logic) and then want to join with another table for the new column. Please check this following query work for you or not-

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
    CASE  c.userid 
        WHEN '1' THEN c.user2id 
        ELSE c.userid 
    END uu 
)A
INNER JOIN  users AS u 
ON   A.uu = u.id
```

as you wants to combine two column's value in one and then wants to join another table based on the new column. Please check this following query works for you or not-

Can you please check this following script-

```
SELECT DISTINCT  * 
FROM users   A
INNER JOIN chats   B 
ON A.id = CASE WHEN b.userid = '1' THEN B.user2id ELSE B.userid END
```

Comment: This query I think has a lot of cost for the database. Do you know the cheaper way?

Comment: I have added a new query above. I can not check the output as I have no data.